# How to restart Meteor

Tags: shell, meteor

If I close the browser tab and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd> to exit the current running meteor process, how do I start meteor again to restart the previous project?

I get the following error:

> $ ~/current/meteor/project meteor
>
> meteor Can't listen on port 3000. Perhaps another Meteor is running?
>
> Running two copies of Meteor in the same application directory will
>   not work. If something else is using port 3000, you can specify an
>   alternative port with --port .

But specifying another port doesn't change the error message.

Comment: Use ctrl-c instead of ctrl-z.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

in Linux <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> suspends the program and `bg` command sends it to background. You can type `fg` command to get back to the program.

After getting back to program, you can close it by <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, then simply start it again by `meteor` command.

Comment: Control-Z suspends it. `bg` then sends it to the background, or `fg` sends it to the foreground.

Answer (score 6):

You can also use the `sudo killall -9 node` command to stop all meteor projects and then `meteor` to start the one you want in your folder of choice.

Comment: One word of caution. This may inadvertently kill other node processes.

Answer (score 1):

if the meteor process is quit improperly (empty battery for example) you may also get this error.

in this case running

```
meteor reset
```

will help.

this will also delete the database of the project you are in when executing this command

so dont do this if your database is filled with valuable data.

have fun :)

*i know your question was answered, but i guess people will find this post when searching for the error i described too since the error messages are the same.

Answer (score 0):

In case you're on a  Mac, the same process applies:

<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd> suspends the Meteor server which you can then:

`bg` to keep it running in the background

`fg` to bring the background running process to the foreground

<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> to close it.

Comment: Please give reasons when downvoting — My answer applies perfectly to the case.

Answer (score -3):

This could be a permissions issue on your box depending on your permissions.

Does running:

```
sudo meteor
```

From the appropriate directory fix the issue?

Comment: Ctrl+c fixed the problem for me.

Comment: Nope, sudo made no difference. Yaak's answer (ctrl+c) fixed it. If you forget (send it to the background with ctrl+z), like Keith said, "fg meteor" brings it to the foreground where youcan continue working on it, or close it properly.