# How can I solve the `--port` error in meteor js

Tags: meteor

When I restart Meteor in linux cent-os, I get the following console error:

> Can't listen on port 3000. Perhaps another Meteor is running?
>
> Running two copies of Meteor in the same application directory will not work. If something else is using port 3000, you can specify an alternative port with --port *<port>*.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to go back to Meteor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12999181/how-to-go-back-to-meteor)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could try running meteor on a different port:

```
meteor --port 8000
```

If you're sure you have nothing on port 3000 running, try killing it off before you run meteor

```
kill -9 mongos
kill -9 node
```

Another alternative is to restart the machine.

Answer (score 4):

You can do it like this:

```
ps -A | grep node
ps -A | grep mongo
```

And after kill them like this:

```
kill -9 number of process
```

Now you can run meteor on port 3000

Answer (score 4):

For Windows, you can [kill meteor like this](https://github.com/meteor/windows-preview/issues/30):

```
taskkill /f /im mongod.exe
taskkill /f /im node.exe
```

Answer (score 2):

in Linux CTRL+Z suspends the program and `bg` command sends it to background. You can type `fg` command to get back to the program.

After getting back to program, you can close it by CTRL+C, then simply start it again by meteor command.

Answer (score 1):

Also, you can choose a higher port number. In my case I was trying port 3001 and I had another meteor instance running on port 3000.

I did `meteor --port 4000` and it launched fine. I then tried 3002 and that worked as well. I wonder if Meteor actually uses 2999 - 3001 (I also tried 2999 and got an error) 
`Unexpected mongo exit code 48. Restarting.`

Comment: When you launch meteor, it launches mongo to start listening on port 3001.

Comment: No, I used the default port of 3000 or any state at the start, and the following (+1) to Mongo.  
That is, the following application can be run through a 2-port, already in 3002, hence the previous 2-port as before - it is 2998.  

Check can be very simple (Mac, Linux):   `ps|grep meteor`

Answer (score 1):

You can reboot CentOS with:

`reboot -h now`

You can reboot Ubuntu with:

`reboot`

Answer (score 1):

Try using `sudo fuser -k 3000/tcp`.

The above command kills the process running on port 3000.
If you want to check the running processes, try `sudo fuser 3000/tcp`.